# Problem with references, Primary and Foreign Keys

Tags: postgresql

I'm really having trouble setting up my first Database for university. I will have to reference the keys from company and employee to works. In a relation that an employee can only work in one company.

I constantly get some error, one after the Primary Key and also the references doesn't really work.

FYI: I'm working on postgresql.

I hope somebody can help me. Thanks for your help

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA p10_1_employee;
Set search_path to p10_1_employee;

CREATE TABLE employee(
    firstname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    lastname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cPKfirstnamelastname PRIMARY KEY(firstname, lastname)
);

CREATE TABLE company(
    companyname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cPKcompanyname PRIMARY KEY (companyname)
);

CREATE TABLE works (
    personenname varchar(40),
    companyname varchar(20)
    CONSTRAINT cPKpersonennamecompanyname PRIMARY KEY (personenname, companyname)
    CONSTRAINT cFKfirstnamelastname FOREIGN KEY (personenname) REFERENCES employee(firstname, lastname),
    CONSTRAINT cFKcompanyname FOREIGN KEY (companyname) REFERENCES company(companyname)
);
```

Comment: Names change, so they are a bad choice for a primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several bugs in the `works` table (missing commas and a wrong number of referencing columns). Here is a working script

```
CREATE TABLE works (
    personenname_firstname varchar(20),
    personenname_lastname varchar(40),
    companyname varchar(20),
    CONSTRAINT cPKpersonennamecompanyname PRIMARY KEY (personenname_firstname, personenname_lastname, companyname),
    CONSTRAINT cFKfirstnamelastname FOREIGN KEY (personenname_firstname, personenname_lastname) REFERENCES employee,
    CONSTRAINT cFKcompanyname FOREIGN KEY (companyname) REFERENCES company
);
```